# How can i readStream from an Iceberg table as source whose snapshots expire?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-iceberg

I am reading with spark streaming an Iceberg table as source, this Iceberg table receives the information from kafka and have compact and expiring old snapshot maintenance options.

I am using this code

```
spark.readStream
  .format("iceberg")
  .option("streaming-skip-delete-snapshots", "true")
  .load(s"${icebergConf.icebergTableQualifier}")
```

My problem is that once an old snapshot is expired the process fails

```
Exception in thread "main" ERROR: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = c084caa6-0907-4781-b6a7-8f8991929f97, runId = 7781194d-298d-4929-be8e-c5407bd98566] terminated with exception: Cannot load current offset at snapshot 1615816462090596768, the snapshot was expired or removed
```

How can I readStream from an Iceberg table whose old snapshots are expiring?

Thanks a lot in advance

I tried to use two options to solve this but none of them worked

1. Enable streaming-skip-delete-snapshots option

   ```
         spark.readStream
           .format("iceberg")
           .option("streaming-skip-delete-snapshots", "true")
           .load(s"${icebergConf.icebergTableQualifier}")
   ```
2. Get timestamp from the newest snapshot to apply stream-from-timestamp configuration

   ```
       if (spark.catalog.tableExists(s"${icebergConf.icebergTableQualifier}.snapshots")) {
         val latestSnapshotTimestampDF = spark.read
           .table(s"${icebergConf.icebergTableQualifier}.snapshots")
           .agg(F.max("committed_at").as("latest_snapshot_timestamp"))

         // Get the latest snapshot timestamp as a Long
         val latestSnapshotTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
           .parse(
             latestSnapshotTimestampDF
               .head()
               .getAs[Long]("latest_snapshot_timestamp")
               .toString)
           .getTime

         logger.info(s"Latest Snapshot Timestamp: ${latestSnapshotTimestamp}")

         spark.readStream
           .format("iceberg")
           .option("streaming-skip-delete-snapshots", "true")
           .option("stream-from-timestamp", latestSnapshotTimestamp)
           .load(s"${icebergConf.icebergTableQualifier}")
       }
   ```

Comment: how frequently are you compacting & expiring the snapshots?

Comment: hello @AlexMerced i am compacting and expiring the snapshots once a day
with this configuration
target file size is 128 mb and about expiring is more than 10 days

Comment: Let me see if I got this right, you have to specify the snapshots for the streamRead to begin reading, but eventually that snapshot expires and when that happens it causes the ongoing process to fail?

Is it possible to restart the process right after your done compacting each day so it's always restarted with a valid snapshot?

Comment: Not exactly, I don't specify any snapshots when i reading (step 1) and when I start process a table it worked fine but after a while that table had a snapshot that after compaction and expire snapshots maintenance options is removed and as a consequence the process fails with this error "Cannot load current offset at snapshot 1615816462090596768, the snapshot was expired or removed"

I tried to specify snapshots to avoid this error but it is not working

Here it's the link with the issue i posted also in Jira with more information
https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/9504

Comment: is this comment more clear? @AlexMerced
if you need more context please tell me
thanks a lot